# Surely it's not a good idea to let people propose sites without confirming their email?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I couldn't figure out why I wasn't counted as following my own proposal, turns out I hadn't confirmed my email address.  (It had been sent to my work email by mistake)

Surely it's not a good idea to let people propose sites without confirming their email?

Also,  "following" your own proposal is a bit strange, but it does get around the lonely looking '0' followers when you start something, so I like it.

[My site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17056/china)

Comment: Re the E-Mail confirmation: Why not? It stands to reason the proposal counts, not the proposer.

Answer (score 2):

We actually already implemented this (or so I thought). It turns out we had a bug whereby a user with >= 50 rep with an unconfirmed email address could still create a proposal. This is fixed now.

Comment: with *bug* you mean your `if(user.eMailConfirmed)` was actually `if(user.rep >= 50)` ? :P