# Area51 sends verification email, but I don't get anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email-verification

I wanted to propose a new Stack Exchange site, but the process required me to verify my email address first. Email address is correct, but no email is getting delivered.

I checked spam folder as well, but nothing that I could see got over.

Looks like a possible bug. Is it?

> I've seen this reported many times, but since answers don't really help me, I asked the question as well, so someone should check what's been happening. Once it was SMTP error, some other time there was a delay etc... Don't really know what's going on in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just fixed a bug in which email verifications were sometimes not sent during proposal creation.

The bug was introduced a month ago while [fixing a related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60250/surely-its-not-a-good-idea-to-let-people-propose-sites-without-confirming-their/60259#60259), but it shouldn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the email was never sent to you.  I've sent it manually, and we'll look into why it's sometimes not getting sent.

Comment: Thank you. I got it after you've sent it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. There is also a link you can click in your user profile to send a confirmation e-mail. I was able to circumvent the issue by using this link (the e-mail then showed up instantly).

Others can probably do the same.